# Trigger shortcode after submit button pressed

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7, shortcode

I need to **execute a shortcode after the user will press the submit button**. I am using Contact form 7 and have inserted the form by a shortcode in the Post edit section.

It's basically a form collecting data and after submit, I will redirect the user to PayPal in a new window. The shortcode for the PayPal button works already on it's own.

I have tried this function but the form seems to get stuck, I get the loading icon forever, the message is delivered but most important, it's not executing my shortcode. Not even a simple `echo "test";`.

```
add_action ('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'after_mail_sent');
function after_mail_sent () {
  echo do_shortcode ('[book]');
}
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Conform that shortcodes is working or not.

Comment: The shortcode is working by itself, if I do [book] in page edit, it does show up on my page. I just don't know how to edit the functions file of that CF7 to load my shortcode. Update => I do get the email even if I am not shown the "success" message, by using that function, but what's in the function doesn't show up.

Comment: I've also realised that I will have to hide the submit button before showing the button from my shortcode.. grr, this is getting worse :/.

Comment: The code for the `[book]` shortcode would help.

Comment: that wouldn't have been of any help, I've already mentioned the shortcode is working fine; it's content is irrelevant given the question

Answer (score 1):

You could customize Contact Form 7 so that once the button is pressed, it leads to a page where you have your shortcode. You basically are making the a page that should be a confirmation just have your shortcode.

This thread has the info on the redirect:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-redirect-to-thank-you-page-on-submit?replies=23

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. If something happens to that link the answer becomes useless. Please try to make your answer here stand alone.

Comment: "I need to execute a shortcode after the user will press the submit button.". This is what I needed.